# how to validate across two different models in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Could anyone please tell me how to validate across two different models in angularjs

**Here is my code:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Utsg7Zr8fsg7zzX5Naib?p=preview I am adding custom validation using custom directive

Requirement

**It should display error when user enter “First” name it check “last name” length if it less then 4 .it should show error.Same in last name if user enter “last name” then check “first name” length is less than 4 .if yes it should show error**

I do the following steps:

1. Type "a" in first field (it become red which is fine).
2. but when Itype "abcderff" in last name why is the first name is red
   ??

   ```
   .directive("testfirst", function() {
       return {
           restrict: "A",
           require: 'ngModel',

           link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelVal) {

               modelVal.$validators.testfirst= function(val) {
                 console.log(attributes.last)
                 console.log((attributes.last && attributes.last.length < 4));
                 if(val.length > 0 && !(attributes.last && attributes.last.length < 4)){

                   return false
                 }
                  return true
               };
               scope.$watch("val", function() {
                   modelVal.$validate();
               });

           }

       };
   }).directive("testlast", function() {
       return {
           restrict: "A",
           require: 'ngModel',

           link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelVal) {

               modelVal.$validators.testlast= function(val) {
                 if(val.length > 0 && !(attributes.first && attributes.first.length < 4)){
                   return false
                 }
                 return true
               };
               scope.$watch("val", function() {
                   modelVal.$validate();
               });

           }

       };
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer I change this content:

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  <form name="myform">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="50%">Field Name</th>
          <th class="smallcol" width="50%">Field Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in c">
          <td ng-if="value.type == 'LABEL'" colspan="2" style="background: #777; color: white;">{{key}}</td>
          <td ng-if="value.type == 'FIELD'">{{key}}</td>

          <td ng-if="value.type == 'FIELD' && isEditableMode && value.editable && value.dataType=='last'">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myform[key].$invalid}">
              <input type="text" name="{{key}}" first="{{getCheck('First')}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-keyup="update(value)" testlast>
            </div>
          </td>

          <td ng-if="value.type == 'FIELD' && isEditableMode && value.editable && value.dataType=='name'">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myform[key].$invalid}">
              <input type="text" last="{{getCheck('Last')}}" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-keyup="update(value)" testfirst>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>
```

Noted :

Test case 1 : It should display error when user enter “First” name it check “last name” length if it less then 4 .it should show error

Test case 2 :  Same in last name if user enter “last name” then check “first name” length is less than 4 .if yes it should show error

Test case 1 finish after that you must to clear value all field. 
after You will test case 2 because css show error wrong. you should handle it again.

[sample code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5rPRfU8PGGs0YwOFA85?p=preview)